# How to pass json data into codeigniter view

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter, view

I have following ajax call and response with json data type. Currently I write the data and html tag directly in js but I think this is not good and hard to read. How can I pass them in Codeigniter view?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "profile/setting",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          var html = "";
          html += "<div>";
          html += "<img src=\"" + baseUrl + data.picture + "\" />";
          html += "<div>" + data.email + "</div>";
          html += "<div>" + data.first_name + " " + data.last_name  + "</div>";
          html += "<div>" + data.address + "</div>";
          html += "<div><input type=\"text\" class=\"input_text_top\"/></div>";
          html += "<div><input type=\"text\" class=\"input_text_middle\"/></div>";
          html += "<div><input type=\"text\" class=\"input_text_bottom\"/></div>";
          html += "<div><input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn_grey\"/></div>";
          html += "</div>";
          $('#result_column').removeAttr('style').html(data);
        }
      });
```

Comment: so you no longer want it to be an ajax call is what youre asking?  or you want to put the script directly in the view?

Comment: I still want it to be an ajax call but I just want the data and html tag write in codeigniter view file. for example: $this->load->view($html_and_data_here)

Comment: If I want to use separate html tag and data value and write them in codeigniter view file. Is that mean I cannot use json?  
I have to use dataType: 'html' ?

Can someone correct me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of options for you:

### 1. Generate the HTML from a CodeIgniter View:

If you change your `dataType` attribute to `dataType: 'html'` you can have the server return a string of html which you can immediately inject into your `#result_column`.

CodeIgniter's `$this->load->view()` comes with a third boolean parameter. It's default is `FALSE`. If you pass `TRUE`, the `$this->load->view()` function *returns* data instead of echoing it to the browser.

What you can do is:

```
$response = $this->load->view("your_ajax_view", $data, TRUE);
//do anything you would need to with the response.
echo $response;
```

### 2. Use a templating system

Like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), [Handlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/), [EJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.EJS) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to inject your returned json data into a custom template. This has the advantage of saving bandwidth because you only transfer the *markup* once (on initial page load) and from that point forward transfer *data* only.

Comment: I think I will choose option 1 as I don't want to use template system

Comment: After some research, I think I better choose a json templating

Comment: If you're application is javascript heavy, Underscore is a swiss-army knife of object and array manipulation. It just happens to come with a templating engine as well. Worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

basically, if you want to do that, you will just take care of it in the profile/setting controller.  then at the end of the controller load your view.  then change your ajax function to just do the html as the data that is returned.  Something like this:

AJAX part:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl + "profile/setting",                
            success: function(data){
               $('#result_column').html(data);
            }
            });
```

controller:

```
function setting()
{
  //whatever your code is, but then just pass the json 
//data you were echoing before to the view file
$data['json_stuff'] = '';//however you generat this
$this->load->view('some view file', $data);
return;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking so it no longer json data?

Comment: ya.  you only need to specifiy it as json if your going to parse json data after the ajax request succeeds or fails.